# How do I navigate an XML document using C# (XNamespace/XElement)

Tags: c#, xml, linq, youtube, namespaces

I am having trouble extracting out a desired element in a C# Windows Phone 8 application that retrieves YouTube data feeds.  The XML document is shown below.  It's from a YouTube playlist feed:

```
<entry gd:etag="W/&quot;YDwqeyM.&quot;" xmlns:gd="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <media:group xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/">
    <media:category label="Science &amp; Technology" scheme="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/categories.cat">Tech</media:category>
    <media:content url="https://www.youtube.com/v/vt7PLhQKYlU?version=3&amp;f=playlists&amp;app=youtube_gdata" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" medium="video" isDefault="true" expression="full" duration="1668" yt:format="5" xmlns:yt="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007" />
    <media:content url="rtsp://r5---sn-p5qlsu7d.c.youtube.com/CiULENy73wIaHAlVYgoULs_evhMYDSANFEgGUglwbGF5bGlzdHMM/0/0/0/video.3gp" type="video/3gpp" medium="video" expression="full" duration="1668" yt:format="1" xmlns:yt="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007" />
    <media:content url="rtsp://r5---sn-p5qlsu7d.c.youtube.com/CiULENy73wIaHAlVYgoULs_evhMYESARFEgGUglwbGF5bGlzdHMM/0/0/0/video.3gp" type="video/3gpp" medium="video" expression="full" duration="1668" yt:format="6" xmlns:yt="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007" />
    <media:credit role="uploader" scheme="urn:youtube" yt:display="TheDigitalDigest" yt:type="partner" xmlns:yt="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007">thedigitaldigest</media:credit>
    <media:description type="plain">Surface 2</media:description>
    <yt:videoid xmlns:yt="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007">vt7PLhQKYlU</yt:videoid>
  </media:group>
</entry>
```

I need to modify the code below that parses the entry using *XNamespace/XElement* methods to look for the **yt:video** element instead of the **id** element.  I can get to the elements that are not prefixed with a namespace without trouble (those that do not contain a colon).  Here is the code that I need to modify:

```
public YouTubeVideo(XNamespace atomns, XElement entry, XNamespace medians)
    {
        var id = entry.Element(atomns.GetName("id")) != null && entry.Element(atomns.GetName("id")).Value != null
            ? entry.Element(atomns.GetName("id")).Value.Split(':').Last()
            : string.Empty;
        VideoUrl = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/" + id;
    }
```

Note, I found this SO post that talks about namespaces:

[Using LINQ to XML to Process XML in Multiple Namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224896/using-linq-to-xml-to-process-xml-in-multiple-namespaces)

My concern is that there's probably a way to pull out **yt:videoid** from the XML without hard-coding the **yt** namespace into the code, since the **yt** namespace is sitting right inside the **yt:videoid** element as an *xmlns* attribute.  Is there a method that selects the namespaced node that has the namespace reference as an attribute?  If not, what is the correct way to select the namespace from an element that carries it as an attribute, and the access the namespaced element's contents?

UPDATE: To get around the current problem I am using the code below.  I still would like to know of a solution that does not ignore namespaces like the code below does:

```
string videoid = (from child in entry.Descendants()
                      where child.Name.LocalName == "videoid"
                      select child.Value).FirstOrDefault();
```

UPDATE: I now have an XPath style query that doesn't ignore namespaces that works, but it seems a bit verbose and I'd like someone to suggest a more streamlined method if there is one.  I know I could add ternary operators, but instead I'm wondering if there's a way to combine the namespace resolutions and the element selects?:

```
        // Get the namespaces for the "media" group, since it contains the "yt" group,
        //  and for the "yt" group itself.
        XNamespace xnsMediaGroup = entry.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("media");
        XNamespace xnsYouTube = entry.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("yt");

        // Got valid namespace references?
        if ((xnsMediaGroup != null) && (xnsYouTube != null))
        {
            // Yes.  Select the media group element.
            XElement xelemMediaGroup = entry.Element(xnsMediaGroup.GetName("group"));

            if (xelemMediaGroup != null)
            {
                // Select the YouTube videoid element.
                XElement xelemYTVideoId = xelemMediaGroup.Element(xnsYouTube.GetName("videoid"));

                if (xelemYTVideoId != null)
                    // Return the video's ID.
                    videoid = xelemYTVideoId.Value;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should read Scott Hanselman's article: [Get namespaces from an XML Document with XPathDocument and LINQ to XML](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GetNamespacesFromAnXMLDocumentWithXPathDocumentAndLINQToXML.aspx)

Comment: Upvoted because that's a good article.  But the core of my latest solution turned out to be the XElement.GetNameSpaceOfPrefix() call, not covered in that article.  Still looking for something less verbose, as stated in the latest update to my original post.